# How to understand large validation rules?

Tags: validation, business-logic

For example I have a long validation rule..

```
 AND ( $User.BypassME__c = False, 
   OR ( AND ( $User.ProfileId = '111', 
   NOT( OR( ISPICKVAL(UserType ,"Superman"), ProfileId = '222'))....
```

How do I read this validation rule? I get very confused. Is there a good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that helps me is to clean it up and make sure everything in the same block aligns vertically:

```
AND(
  $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator',
  TEXT(PRIORVALUE( Status__c )) = 'Active',
  NOT(ISNEW()),
  NOT(ISCHANGED( PIN__c )),
  OR(
    TEXT(Status__c) != 'Inactive',
    ISCHANGED( Address__c ),
    ISCHANGED( City__c ),
    ISCHANGED( Email__c ),
    ISCHANGED( First_Name__c ),
    ISCHANGED( Last_Name__c ),
    ISCHANGED( State__c ),
    ISCHANGED( Zip_4__c ),
    ISCHANGED( Zip_Code__c)))
```

And anything that has more than one parameter should take more than one line.  As you can see, it makes it a lot easier to read and debug.

Comment: Thnx, it helped a lot!